# Python hyperlink inside a loop doesn't loop thought the different id`s of JSON data

Tags: python, for-loop, url, tkinter, hyperlink

I am trying to add buttons within a loop of tkinter with hyperlinks from a JSON file. when I press the buttons the hyperlink stays the same for all of them. it kinda doesn't loop through the URL links with the JSON id.

When I print them they are all different.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen 
import json
import webbrowser
import tkinter as tk    

with urlopen("https:example") as response:
source = response.read()          

data=json.loads(source)


#this is the function that should be triggered with different url each time
def openweb():
   webbrowser.open(url,new=1)

count=0
for product in data:
   id = product['id']  
   name = product['name']  
   price = product['price']  
   aciklama = product['description']  

   #these are the links for the buttons
   url = "https://www.example.com/tr-tr/i/"+id  
   #and here are the buttons with the command openweb defined above
   element = tk.Button(canvasFrame, text='Button', borderwidth=0, bg="#EBEBEB",command=openweb)  
   element.grid(row=count,column=1,padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")  
   T = tk.Text(canvasFrame, height=2, width=30)  
   T.insert(tk.INSERT,count)  
   T.grid(row=count,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)  
   count=count+1  

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you are trying to print, it is printing inside for loop. But every time your ID is getting overwritten in URL and the last ID will appear in final URL. Also I cant see URL is getting assign anywhere inside for loop

Comment: What makes you think your buttons will print something different? All of the have the same exact command. To  an external function that is only called when the buttons are presses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a `lambda` in the command of your buttons.

The problem here is that within your loop you assign/overwrite URL with each loop so the only thing URL can be is the last value in the loop. In order to keep the correct value lets use a lambda to assign the URL to a lambda variable so it will be kept in the button command.

We will also need to update your function to accept an argument so we can pass that URL.

Try this updated function and loop and let me know if you have any questions.

```
def openweb(url):
   webbrowser.open(url, new=1)

count = 0

for product in data:
   id = product['id']  
   name = product['name']  
   price = product['price']  
   aciklama = product['description']  
   url = "https://www.example.com/tr-tr/i/"+id  
   tk.Button(canvasFrame, text='Button', borderwidth=0, bg="#EBEBEB",
             command=lambda u=url: openweb(u)).grid(row=count, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")  
   txt = tk.Text(canvasFrame, height=2, width=30)  
   txt.insert(tk.INSERT, count)  
   txt.grid(row=count, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)  
   count += 1
```

Comment: @abdussamed17 You never actually use the anything from the URL to create your buttons. There wont ever be a time where the button can assume what you were wanting just because a value was defined at the same time as the button. You have to be specific. That is why we use `lambda` here. It is actually used a lot in loops like this due to an annoying problem that occurs if you do not. If my answer works for you please make sure to select the check mark to indicate you question has been answered.

Comment: Mike thank you very much for your detailed informations.